# Python 3 webbrowser module problems with chrome on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, web

Hi guys I couldn't solve following problem:

```
import webbrowser
word = "cat"
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/#q=' + word)
webbrowser.get('firefox').open('http://www.google.com/#q=' + word)
```

So the task is simple: Open a link with Python 3. 
I'm working on Ubuntu and chrome is my default browser. But if I try to open a link with the default browser (line 3), it only opens the browser without the website.
When done with Firefox it works how it is supposed to.

Does anyone has a suggestion why this is so?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly in my system

Comment: Try using this 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' instead of yours

Comment: No, that also does not work (with chrome). I guess it has to do with linux and the permissions of google chrome maybe?